# Any suggestion for 3rd parties .NET web form generator/builder

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Do you have any suggestion for a product/solution that allow clients to create web forms online?

This is the scenario:
Superuser creates web forms and publish them for further usage (for other users of the site).

I need asp.net or asp.net MVC. It would be good if it is possible to buy licence with source code, so I can customize and adapt the solution. I need to import this project in my .NET solution. 
Any help is appreciated.

Edit:  I want to allow clients of web site, to be able to create their own web forms.
Thay would be some kind of superusers or admin users.
Clients have no tech knowledge. Do you have any good experience with this? Or do I need do code this from the scratch?
Info Path is great tool, but it's only desktop app.It doesn't work with web.

Some .Net solutions like this http://wufoo.com/

Another great Product is this http://www.frevvo.com/frevvo/web/static/home

Comment: I was trying to answer this myself recently. http://surveymaster.codeplex.com/ was the best I found. It is missing alot, but what is there is solid.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Forms

Features:

- Build HTML form fields at runtime from field definitions that are stored anywhere you like
- Renders CSS friendly HTML
- Automatic input validation of required fields and regular expressions applied to text fields

http://mvcdynamicforms.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

This article from Phil Haack might be useful.  It discusses storing views in the database and allowing users to customize them.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx

Some open-source Content Management Systems (CMS) have HTML form editors built in that are fairly intuitive.  Here's one: http://n2cms.com/wiki/Edit-Interface.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This project claims to be an opensource form builder:
http://websurvey.codeplex.com/

Comment: This question was long ago. We have built in-house our own form generator with help of jQuery library

Comment: Hi Nemke, we are also looking for a control for this or trying to build one by ourself. Just curious to know how long it took to develop it in-house.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have your own CMS, many CMS offerings, like [N2](http://n2cms.com/) can be used as a library in your existing MVC web app.

You can look at N2's source code because it basically does what you want to do, so you could call their .DLL or refactor your code and borrow some of theirs.

I think they use Telerik rich text controls to allow users with sufficient rights to create their own content...

Answer (score -4):

You might want to consider a content management system.
There are plenty out there that allow users in various roles to publish content.
I've personally used epiServer, but it doesn't come cheap
There are plenty of other .net based open source cms solutions such as Drupal.

Comment: I already have custom developed company CMS. I need to add this new capability.

Comment: And Drupal is PHP not .NET. I did't ask which open source CMS to use.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining myself properly.
Certain CMS applications allow the creation of 'Page Templates' - this is something your user super user could do.
This then allows other users to create an instance of the template and add content through a WYSIWYG editor and publish it as a 'new web page'. Most CMS packages will also let users create 'forms' and store the responses.

Hope this is clearer, or maybe I'm not fully understanding your requirement?